# Difference between "Delete Customer" and "End Reseller Relationship" in G-Suite?

Tags: google-workspace, google-reseller-api

What is the difference between the "Delete Customer" option in the new Channel Service console vs the "End Reseller Relationship" option in the old Reseller Admin Console? The option to "delete customer" is not in the old console and the option to "end reseller relationship" is not present in the new console. Are these both the same? What's the difference?